# How can I find a USB device's PID and VID given only the drive letter in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net

Trying to display in 2 seperate labels the PID and VID of a USB when it's drive letter is selected in a listbox, but I haven't figured out how to get the PID and VID of that particular drive letter.

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head, but I'd suggest looking at WMI and the Storage Management API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh830612(v=vs.85).aspx - note that using VB.NET for WMI is an act of self-flagellation.

Comment: Hi @Dai ,  Why using VB.NET for `WMI` is an act of self-flagellation?